# Could not load custom lint while expo managed build

Tags: android, react-native, deployment, expo

The app is created with the help of expo cli(managed workflow). After completing all the required procedure for build, I build this app and encountered with a white screen while opening the apk file. It's working completely fine in development mode and after publishing it on expo it's working fine.

Problem arises after build took place. Please guide me on this one where I'm getting things wrong.

[after opening the apk nothing appears on screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8364a.png)

[While building with expo build:android -t apk cmd:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lXVz.png)

[app.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGw4i.png)

[app.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSB9r.png)

[App.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SC5xv.png)

[App.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1BUn.png)

[App.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0TCc.png)

[App.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10ZU6.png)

Comment: There are dozens of variables that can cause this issue. Try to use ADB LOG CAT to discover issues. It's a painful debugging process but it should help

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat

Answer (score 0):

This can be due to the JS crash. There are multiple cases where JS crashes can occur. i.e. accessing undefined variables or accessing a property of an undefined object etc.

You can check the *logcat* in android studio for the JS-specific error while opening your app. or you can also log with the command **adb logcat**.
https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat